# Horizontal Menu Issues

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble getting a horizontal menu to line up correctly in IE9 and Firefox.

This is what it displays like in IE and Firefox:
[image]

And this is what it displays like in Chrome, Safari and Opera:

[image]

I keep getting that damn overflow!
What might be the issue?

My CS:

```
.service-list {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    display:block;
    width:960px;
}
#services-content .service-list li {
    float:left;
    display:inline;
}
#services-content .service-list li a {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    color:#F37FA8;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:0 20px;
    background-color:pink;
    font-weight:400;
}
#services-content .service-list li a:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
}
#services-content .service-list li.last a {
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-right:0;
}
#services-content .service-list li.first a {
    padding-left:0 !important;
}
```

The menu is spat out by wordpress.

Thanks,

Nick

Comment: We really need to see your code to be able to help you....

Comment: Ok i added the CSS i am using.

Comment: It would be easier to check & debug if you can make a fiddle [jsfiddle.net] & share that link

Comment: go direct here:
http://www.xqusme.com/kx/

User: client
Password: client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the css on the site you posted.  The inconsistency may be caused by your use of `font-size:120%` on the a tags (line 186 of style.css).

When you pop open firebug in firefox or developer tools in chrome, notice in the 'computed style' section that chrome is rendering 120% as 17px while firefox is rendering it as 16.8px.

How the browsers render this differently is a little out of scope, but you may want to try using pixels or ems instead.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Awesome, that solves the top menus problem, but the bottom menu is still experiencing the same inconsistency :S

Comment: Tough one. I'm seeing the same prob in firefox/chrome (on mac).  It looks like you're just out of pixels.  Try reducing the padding on the a tags till they all fit, then float the last li tag right to get it flush with the right side.  Then the only adjustment would then be put the pink background on the ul instead of the li tags.

Comment: Pink background is there just as a guide for me to see if it is sitting all the way at the end of the div.

Will give floating the last one a try, quite weird that it works fine in Chrome, Safari and Opera though :/

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that there is a 40 pixel space between each item, and every item is being floated left, and this is making everything wrap when there's not enough room in each line.

You could try changing `padding: 0 20px;` in `#services-content .service-list li a` to something smaller, say `padding: 0 10px;`

Comment: Yeah i do realise that, but i want the menu to sit flush side to side

Comment: Chrome, Safari and Opera show exactly what i am try to achieve but nothing else wants to play nice..